# Put Gdk.RGBA into Gtk.ListStore, get it back, found a different color

Tags: python, gtk3, pygobject, gdk

I put a `Gdk.RGBA` into a `Gtk.ListStore`, and tried to get it back:

```py
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk, Gdk

model = Gtk.ListStore(int, int, Gdk.RGBA)
bgcolor = Gdk.RGBA(red=1, green=0, blue=0)
model.append([0, 10, bgcolor])

print(bgcolor)
print(model[0][2])
```

I found a different color:

```py
Gdk.RGBA(red=1.000000, green=0.000000, blue=0.000000, alpha=1.000000)
Gdk.RGBA(red=0.000000, green=0.000000, blue=0.000000, alpha=1.000000)
```

What is going on here?

Comment: That's probably not a *different* color, rather a representation of the default (0, 0, 0, 1) color. I guess gdk.RGBA isn't directly supported and model casts it wrong. Maybe it just picks first 4 bytes of your gdk.RGBA instance.

Comment: If in the end you used one of the answers, would you mind marking it as accepted? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It is a bug in Gtk. For example this shows that the R and G values get lost:

```
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk, Gdk

model = Gtk.ListStore(Gdk.RGBA)
bgcolor = Gdk.RGBA(red=0, green=0, blue=0, alpha=0)
model.append([bgcolor])
bgcolor = Gdk.RGBA(red=0.5, green=0.5, blue=0.5, alpha=0.5)
model.append([bgcolor])
bgcolor = Gdk.RGBA(red=1, green=1, blue=1, alpha=1)
model.append([bgcolor])

print(model[0][0])
print(model[1][0])
print(model[2][0])
```

Because the results are:

```
Gdk.RGBA(red=0.000000, green=0.000000, blue=0.000000, alpha=0.000000)
Gdk.RGBA(red=0.000000, green=0.000000, blue=0.500000, alpha=0.500000)
Gdk.RGBA(red=0.000000, green=0.000000, blue=1.000000, alpha=1.000000)
```

There was a bug report filed with Gnome/Gtk a while back, but I can't find it anymore. I believe it got lost when the infrastructure moved to GitLab.

A possible workaround is to use separate columns for the RGBA values, and construct/deconstruct the RGBA every time. Example:

```
model = Gtk.ListStore(float, float, float, float)
in_color = Gdk.RGBA(red=0.5, green=0.5, blue=0.5, alpha=0.5)
model.append([in_color.red, in_color.green, in_color.blue, in_color.alpha])
out_color = Gdk.RGBA()
out_color.red = model[0][0]
out_color.green = model[0][1]
out_color.blue = model[0][2]
out_color.alpha = model[0][3]

print(out_color)
```

Comment: Here is the bug you mention, I suppose, https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/pygobject/-/issues/59 Comment there says, that setting RGBA works well and that the problem is with retrieving it only.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answer of @theGtknerd , there might be an easier workaround. USe a column type of `object` instead of `Gdk.RGBA`.

```
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk, Gdk

model = Gtk.ListStore(int, int, object)  # Instead of Gdk.RGBA
bgcolor = Gdk.RGBA(red=1, green=0, blue=0)
model.append([0, 10, bgcolor])

print(bgcolor)
print(model[0][2])
```

Output:

```
Gdk.RGBA(red=1.000000, green=0.000000, blue=0.000000, alpha=1.000000)
Gdk.RGBA(red=1.000000, green=0.000000, blue=0.000000, alpha=1.000000)
```